# Why does drawing one card at a time increase the probability of choosing the Ace of Spades?

Tags: probability, conditional-probability

If you draw 5 cards from a standard deck of 52 cards, then the probability of your hand having the Ace of Spades is:
$$\frac{51\choose 4}{52\choose 5} = \frac{51!5!47!}{4!47!52!} = \frac{5}{52}$$
If, however, you choose one card a time until you've drawn 5 cards, the probability of having the Ace of Spades is:
$$\frac{1}{52}+\frac{1}{51}+\frac{1}{50}+\frac{1}{49}+\frac{1}{48}=\frac{433507}{4331600}\approx\frac{1}{10}>\frac{5}{52}$$
Why does choosing one card a time increase the probability of finding the Ace of Spades, when the resulting hands are equivalently drawn?

Comment: Hint: instead of drawing 5 cards one at a time, let's say you draw 34. Would you then say your probability of drawing the ace of spades is $1/52 + 1/51 + \ldots + 1/19 \approx 1.04 > 1$?

Comment: Another hint :  What you wanted to do is compute P(X=1)+P(X=2)+..+P(X=5)...with P(x=k) representing the probability of the Ace of Spade drawn exactly at the k th draw.This is one way to find the answer (not the most simple) but one legit way as these are disjunctive cases. The problem comes from how you compute these probabilities. For P(X=2), for example, If you had to answer the question "what is the probability that the ace of space is drawn **exactly** at the second draw, would you find 1/51 ?

Comment: It's not actually homework, just a genuine question. But I think I know what you're saying: I'm conflating the idea of the geometric distribution and dependent draws. So, it'd be better to say $P(X=1)+P(X=2|X\neq 1)+\dots+P(X=5|X\neq 1,2,3,4)$?

Comment: One thing I can't figure out is, why does it cancel out to $5/52$?

$P(X=1) = 1/52$, $P(X=2\mid X\neq 1)=P(X=2\cap X\neq 1)/P(X\neq 1)=((51/52)*(1/51)/(51/52))$, giving me the original (incorrect) sum of fractions?

Comment: Focus on P(X=2∩X≠1) = P(X=2 |X≠1) * P(X≠1). What is that? How does the answer to this relate to probability of getting an ace of spaces for the first time on the 2nd card drawn?

Comment: Well there has a been a little misunderstanding. What you want to compute is indeed P(X=1)+P(X=2∩X≠1)... not P(X=1)+P(X=2|X≠1)... Indeed P(X=2∩X≠1) represents what you want : the probability that the ace is drawn exactly at the second draw.

Comment: I got it! $1/52+((51/52)*(1/51))+\dots+((51/52)*(50/51)*(49/50)*(48/49)*(1/48))=5/52$
You're right, it's a very convoluted way of getting the answer, but it does work out correctly. Though, of course, the intuition that drawing the correct card out of the pack has a probability of $1/52$, so drawing it $5$ times is $5$ times the probability is a lot more intuitive

Thank you for all your help

Comment: Your answer is right but your intuition is wrong. If you apply your "intuition" to other problems, you may get the wrong answer. I said it had a remarkable and unexpected property. Other problems generally won't have this property, so your intuition will be wrong.

Comment: Well, given the OP has understood how to reconcile the probability calculations, someone should write an answer along those lines, or this will likely go unanswered. Perhaps @brumar or AJS could take parts from the comments to briefly outline the error in the original question in an answer.

Comment: @MarkL.Stone Which intuition is wrong, with regards to this question? Is it that of drawing $5$ cards is $5$ times the probability?

Also, is the remarkable and unexpected property the fact that the messy multiplication cancels out to a neat ratio?

Comment: The remarkable and unexpected thing is that the Probability of getting the Ace of Spades (for the first time) on each draw is 1/52, (which of course ends up at 52/52 = 1 as the probability that one of the 52 draws will be the Ace of Spades). I think your intuition about multiplying the probability of the first draw being the Ace of Spades is not generally applicable, and could lead you astray on other problems. It just happens to give the correct answer in this case.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

As @Glen_b suggested, it would be a good idea to summarize the comments part in an answer. I'll do that and also give an alternative for the formula related to the probabilistic point of view at the end of the answer. The apparent contradiction between the two computations came from this line :

> the probability of having the Ace of Spades is:
>   $$\frac{1}{52}+\frac{1}{51}+\frac{1}{50}+\frac{1}{49}+\frac{1}{48}=\frac{433507}{4331600}\approx\frac{1}{10}>\frac{5}{52}$$

The idea behind this computation was good but the logic was flawed. If we sum the probability of the Ace of Spade drawn exactly at the k th draw with k going from 1 to 5, we have the probability we want. But $\frac{1}{51}$, for example, does not represent the probability that the ace of spade is **exactly drawn** at the second attempt but the probability that the ace of space is drawn at the second attempt **given that it has not been drawn at the first one**.

AJS finally found the right formula

> I got it! $1/52+((51/52)∗(1/51))+⋯+((51/52)∗(50/51)∗(49/50)∗(48/49)∗(1/48))=5/52$

With the idea that the probability to exactly draw the ace of spade at the $k$ th trial is the probability to **not draw** the ace of spade during previous attempts.... $$(51/52)*(50/51)...(52-k+1)/(52-k+2)$$...multiplied by the probability to draw the card at the $k$ th attempt $$1/(52-k+1)$$

---

A general rule of thumb that I have to avoid this kind of error is to be cautious when it comes to adding probabilities. If you can turn your problem around to avoid additions to the profit of multiplications, this is less prone to error.
A more classic approach giving a shorter path would have been to consider that the probability of having the Ace of Spades after 5 draw is 1-(the probability to **not draw** it with 5 draws) which gives, as you know : $$1-(51/52)*(50/51)*(49/50)*(48/49)*(47/48)=1-47/52=5/52$$

Comment: Thank you, brumar. I appreciate you taking the time to write it out.